# Advantage of using DataBinding in RecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, kotlin-android-extensions

I'm new to Kotlin and DataBinding, and based on the [Google I/O Android App on Github](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/89df01ebc19d9a46495baac4690c2ebfa74946dc/mobile/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/speaker/SpeakerAdapter.kt) I wrote an adapter that works but I'm not being able to completely understand why would someone prefer DataBinding over traditional methods? Is there an advantage in this case?:

```
 internal class RecyclerAdapterKt : RecyclerView.Adapter<BaseViewHolder>() {

    private val data = ArrayList<Item>()

    ...

    /* with data binding */
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): BaseViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        return BaseViewHolder.BasicItemViewHolder(ItemViewBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BaseViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = data[position]
        (holder as BaseViewHolder.BasicItemViewHolder).bind(item)
    }

    // without data binding
    //    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): BaseViewHolder {
    //        val view = from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false)
    //        return BaseViewHolder(view)
    //    }
    //
    //    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BaseViewHolder, position: Int) {
    //        val item = data[position]
    //        holder.tv_title.text = item.title
    //        holder.tv_message.text = item.message
    //    }

    ...

  sealed class BaseViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    class BasicItemViewHolder(
        val binding: ItemViewBinding
    ) : BaseViewHolder(binding.root) {

        fun bind(item : Item) {
            binding.tvTitle.text = item.title
            // Difference with using itemView.tv_title.text?
            binding.tvMessage.text = item.message            
        }
    }
  }
```

Why not accessing directly the layout views in fun bind() through itemView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it will reduce a lot of boilerplate code in bind function of your ViewHolder. The trick lies in the XML and bind function of the Viewholder

With data-binding in place, your ViewHolder class will be follows

```
class BaseViewHolder(private val itemViewBinding: ItemViewBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemViewBinding.root) {
    fun bind(item: Item) {
         itemViewBinding.item = item
         itemViewBinding.executePendingBindings()
    }
}
```

Suppose before data-binding, you XML file item_view.xml is as follows

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width ="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/tvTitle"/>
        <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/tvMessage/>
</LinearLayout>
```

After data-binding, you XML file item_view.xml will be as follows

```
<layout>
    <data>
       <variable name="item"
                 type="com.sample.Item"/>
       <!--your Item model should be defined in the packagename com.sample-->
    </data>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width ="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
          android:text="@{item.title}"/>
        <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/tvMessage"
          android:text="@{item.message}"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thereby the bind function will be the same irrespective of how many more attributes we add in Item model class. So the **advantage is to reduce in boilerplate code**.

Comment: But still not sure, in my case I can save adding the few Views to the ViewHolder but instead I need to add databinding to my gradle, I need to modify my layout, add a reference to each view to the the data model, adapt the RecyclerAdapter to use binding, that's not little code.

Comment: The power of data-binding lies in the complex views and workflows. It will reduce tons of code. Maybe try complex views with and without data-binding. In simple views, it has very less impact